# Yocto: how to configure an out-of-tree kernel module recipe that uses "inherit module"?

Tags: yocto, kernel-module, bitbake, kbuild, yocto-recipe

I have written a simple `inherit module` recipe to build a third-party out-of-tree kernel module called [u-dma-buf](https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf):

```
SUMMARY = "User space mappable DMA Buffer"
DESCRIPTION = "${SUMMARY}"

LICENSE = "BSD-2-Clause"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=bebf0492502927bef0741aa04d1f35f5"

inherit module

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf.git"
SRCREV = "9b943d49abc9c92a464e4c71e83d1c479ebbf80e"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-u-dma-buf"
```

This works correctly and generates the module file `/lib/modules/[version]/extra/u-dma-buf.ko` in the image.

However, looking at the docs there is an option that can be enabled: `CONFIG_U_DMA_BUF_MGR` that is disabled by default. If I can somehow enable this, then I can expect to find `/lib/modules/[version]/extra/u-dma-buf-mgr.ko` in the image also.

The project has a [Kconfig](https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf/blob/master/Kconfig) file. Does bitbake have support for integrating Kbuild configuration outside of the kernel tree? If so, how do I hook into this and enable `CONFIG_U_DMA_BUF_MGR`? And if not, what's my best option, other than patching the `Kconfig` file to change the default to "y"? (EDIT: this probably won't work, as kernel sources need to be modified to incorporate Kbuild anyway - so probably a dead end unless it's a specific feature of bitbake I haven't encountered yet).

I see that the upstream Makefile also has the option `CONFIG_U_DMA_BUF_MGR=m` that could be used to enable this feature outside of Kbuild. I'm not sure how to pass that to the `make` command line though - would I need to write a custom `do_compile` task? Looking at the `module.bbclass` code, I can't see any provision for passing such an option to `oe_runmake`. Should I just copy/paste `module_do_compile()` from `module.bbclass` and add `CONFIG_U_DMA_BUF_MGR=m`? Is that the best way to do this?

So my question is, given I'm using `inherit module`, what is the proper way to enable this configuration option, given the recipe I have?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Yocto kernel development [docs](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/current/kernel-dev/common.html#incorporating-out-of-tree-modules):

> If your module Makefile uses a different variable, you might want to override the do_compile step

That suggests to me that the correct and intended course of action in this case is to copy/paste `module_do_compile()` as a `do_compile()` override, and modify accordingly (add `CONFIG_U_DMA_BUF_MGR=m`):

```
do_compile() {
    unset CFLAGS CPPFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS
    oe_runmake KERNEL_PATH=${STAGING_KERNEL_DIR}   \
           KERNEL_VERSION=${KERNEL_VERSION}    \
           CC="${KERNEL_CC}" LD="${KERNEL_LD}" \
           AR="${KERNEL_AR}" \
               O=${STAGING_KERNEL_BUILDDIR} \
           KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS="${KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS}" \
           CONFIG_U_DMA_BUF_MGR=m \
           ${MAKE_TARGETS}
}
```

Additionally, add the new module to `RPROVIDES_${PN}`:

```
RPROVIDES_${PN} += "kernel-module-u-dma-buf kernel-module-u-dma-buf-mgr"
```